# Laravel Storing Image File Retrieved From External Url in Spesific Folder

Tags: laravel

I'm getting users' profile pictures from another site. I want to create a folder for users who have a URL for the image. Because every user's profile picture must be in its own file. This is what I want to do. I'm running with custom artisan commands.

```html
foreach ($adminUser as $user) {
  $a= DB::table('users')->where('email', $user['email'])->first();
  
  if($a) {
      echo "\n ", $a->name, " this user already exists. \n";
      continue;
  } else {
    $a = User::create($user);
    echo "\n ", $user['name'], " created. \n";
    
    if (isset($user['link']) && strlen($user['link']) > 0) {
        $folder_Path = public_path().'/user_images/' . $a->id;
        File::makeDirectory($folder_Path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
        
        $contents = file_get_contents($user['link']);
        $file_name = basename($user['link']);
        
        Storage::disk('uploads')->put($file_name, $contents);
        $this->info(" |--> Profile picture uploaded.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Could you please describe your problem.

Comment: I want push images to users own file.  example users-id-1 -> 21451-jhon-doe.jpeg , users-id-2 ->jane-doe-2424124.jpg